# How to add viewportwidth with pixels in css?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a width of 50vw, and has a padding of 25px on all sides. I need to add an element to the right of it fixed, so I need to add 50vw and 25px. Is it possible to do so in pure css, or should i use less? if i have to, how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to add 50vw and 25px

That's what `calc` is for.

> The calc() CSS function lets you perform calculations when specifying CSS property values. It can be used anywhere a `<length>`, `<frequency>`, `<angle>`, `<time>`, `<number>`, or `<integer>` is allowed.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

```
width:calc(50vw + 25px);
```